# How can I remove this piece from my bathroom sink handle?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet, plumbing-fixture

I have been trying to remove an old bathroom faucet for two days and I'm stuck.
I can't remove the old faucet handles because I can't seem to remove the part shown in the picture (the big nut and the waterline connector socket pointing toward the camera).

[image: part I can't remove]

I have tried using a normal wrench, a basic wrench, channel locks, etc. Thinking maybe it was rusted on, I applied a heaping amount of wd-40 to try to break that down but it didn't work. I'm honestly not 100 percent sure this even comes off at this point. But I can't even get around it to remove the other gold looking nut at the top.

I'm just stuck on what to do next. There's barely any room under my sink which has made this a nightmare  any and all help will be much appreciated

Comment: Probably need a basin wrench or crow's foot wrench/spanner as mention in this answer.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/150779/how-can-i-unscrew-this-nut-with-little-clearance?rq=1

Comment: With brass nut, might want a crow's foot flare wrench instead of regular wrench to prevent rounding the corners.

Answer (score 1):

That type faucet is usually installed on the sink before the sink top is laid into place. Once you set the sink top in place there is not enough room to get a wrench in to loosen a tight fitting that you are experiencing. Lift the sink top off the cabinet, replace the faucet or make necessary repairs and reinstall the top.

Comment: I agree with this suggestion, however, do you have a tip on how to remove a sink that's been set in some form of caulk or, even worse, construction adhesive (as they often are) without destroying the sink and/or cabinet?

Answer (score 0):

My general rule of thumb is that if the plumbing is 20 years old or more, it usually has to be cut off. And often, even if the plumbing is not 20 years old! Try cutting the upper nut with a Dremel tool outfitted with a metal cutting bit. Also make a similar vertical cut in the lower piece or just hack the whole lower part off.

This suggestion assumes that you can't get a sawzall or hacksaw in there and you don't want to remove the sink.